# transform.EulerAngles Issue Around Circle

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a flat circle, and when I click on it using my Touch script, I can rotate it around. However, if I end up touching the center of the circle, it will flip itself to the opposite. Its kind of wonky. I think its ultimately my math skills here but if someone could take a look that would be appreciative.

```
float changeY = 0;
    // touch position
    Vector3 pos = touch.worldPos;
    Vector2 curLineEnd = new Vector2(pos[0], pos[2]);
    float curLineDistance = GetDistance(new Vector2(lineStart[0], lineStart[1]), curLineEnd);

    if (curLineDistance < edgeWidth) {
        return;
    }

    if(curLineDistance < 0.6)
    {
        float angle = GetAngle(curLineEnd, startLineEnd);

        if (angle > lastAngle+2) 
        {
            changeY += 5;
        }

        else if (angle < lastAngle-2) 
        {
            changeY -= 5;
        }

        lastAngle = angle;
        Debug.Log(angle);

        //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(270, angle + lastY, 0);
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,changeY),Space.World);
    }






    public float GetAngle(Vector2 lineOneEnd, Vector2 lineTwoEnd)
{
    float a = lineOneEnd[0] - lineStart[0];
    float b = lineOneEnd[1] - lineStart[1];
    float c = lineTwoEnd[0] - lineStart[0];
    float d = lineTwoEnd[1] - lineStart[1];
    float lineOneTan = Mathf.Atan2(a, b);
    float lineTwoTan = Mathf.Atan2(c, d);
    float angle = (lineOneTan - lineTwoTan) * 180 / Mathf.PI;
    return angle;
}
```

Comment: I've made it a bit better by using Transform.Rotate instead. The issue that I didnt use it before was because I wasnt sure how to manipulate the angles to increase the Rotation or decrease. I decided to create a variable that just increments when the angle is higher than it was on the last pass. However, it could still use some work regarding how tight it is. It jitters slightly, but nowhere near as bad as it had before.

Comment: You can resolve the jittering by building a little bit of a damper into the system. The variable containing your touch might fluctuate by about .00005. This causes a slight shaking. If you made it so that it would only recognize movement greater than say .05, you would erase a lot of the jitter.